# browser not responding while rendering data to create table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

I am using ajax call to get json data.The data contains array of say 10000 size.

```
data.LocationQuality.forEach(function(datum){
}
```

I am using this loop to go through all the element and create tr with filling all the td's using datum.

Problem I am facing is that because of the large amount of data.The loop is taking lots of time and ultimately the browser shows not responding and I have to kill the page.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pagination.

Comment: I have to whole data with me.How to add pagination after that.I dont have the option to send query to server again for next set of data.

Comment: Aside from using pagination, when you still wish to add many items, make sure to add them all to a table in memory and then add the one table to the dom, rather than many times adding one row to the dom.

Comment: @RenéWolferink Can you be please more clear on this point.How to do that.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things to be said here.

Firstly, as mentioned, pagination would definitely be the best solution for this. Keeping 10000 rows in memory is not a problem for browsers nowadays, but displaying 10000 rows in a table often does take ages. Only displaying 20 rows at a time for example, is much slower.

A solution like jqGrid does not require ajax (but does support it). You can load you data once and the grid will keep the data in memory and only displays a number of items at once, with navigational buttons to flip through pages.

You can get it here: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6

Secondly, something should be said about the dom. I'm expecting that you are currently adding a row to the dom 10000 times. This is much much slower than building the table in memory and then adding the one table with 10000 rows in one step. It will still be slow, but not as slow as hitting the dom so many times.

So rather than

```
$.each(data, function (index, row) {
    $('#yourTable').append('your row definition'); // hitting the dom for each row
}
```

do this instead

```
var table = $('<table></table>');
$.each(data, function (index, row) {
    table.append('your row definition'); // adding it to the table in memory
}
$('#yourTable').replace(table); // hit the dom once
```

Comment: The reason my example uses jQuery is that it was one of the tags in the question. It's also possible using plain old javascript if you prefer, for which @donnywals provided a nice link.

Answer (score 0):

Without code this is a stab in the dark:

1: optimise your page creation loop. DOM operations are very slow - you might be able to improve things by doing them in a different way

2: download your data bit by bit. As the user scrolls your page make another AJAX call to get the next portion of the data.

3: download all the data, but then render only a page at a time.

Comment: No I do not have such option to send another query to the server . I can send the query once and I am getting all of them at time.

Comment: Ok - download all the data, then render only the parts you need to display - pagination. Can you post the code that creates the page?

Answer (score 0):

You also might want to look at this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fdocument.createDocumentFragment

It allows you to create large parts of the DOM without adding them yet. That way you can build your table and append it to the DOM in one go, should be a lot faster then just appending rows all the time

Answer (score 0):

You have problem displaying large number of data, and you can't get data in multiple queries?

So, get all data in one call, parse them and place in array, and do pagination with that "local" array.

Instead of requesting data from server to do pagination, just get data from "local" array.